# DataTables button and search box custom position

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I am using DataTables and using Bootstrap 3 styling. Can anybody please tell me how to achieve this kind of layout for my buttons and search box? (I am using Adobe Photoshop to generate this view)

[image]

Comment: Welcome - and please remember to take the [tour] and read [ask] for guidelines on how to improve your question.

Comment: You can take a look at [How to rearrange DataTables controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66689689/how-to-rearrange-datatables-controls/66698550#66698550). You can also look at [How can we change width of search fields in DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816229/how-can-we-change-width-of-search-fields-in-datatables/29930710#29930710). You should be able to adapt those approaches to your specific needs. Then, if you are still stuck, you can ask a specific question and show us your specific code.

Comment: You can manipulate it through the dom like listed here: [dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)